# Can I change the location of the view scripts in Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

Right now the view scripts for my [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) application are located in the application/views/scripts directory. Is it possible to change this location to something that is configurable?

I am assuming this goes somewhere in the `index.php` file or my `application.ini` file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For convenience ZF automatically sets the view script path to be module/views/scripts/controller/action.phtml

You can add a script path via `$view->addScriptPath('/path/to/view/scripts')` which adds this new path to the stack of available view script paths. It checks the last one set first, then checks on the one before until it finds a file.

Or you can reset the script path via `$view->setScriptPath('/path/to/view/scripts')`

If you need to do this for a controller place this in your _init() method. If you need it for your entire application I'd recommend sticking it in your Bootstrap.

I believe it's also possible to place this in application.ini via: `resources.view.basePath = "/path/to/views/"`

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.controllers.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution using partial guesswork with the application.ini file.  Here are the two Entries you can change in Zend Framework 1.11.12.

```
resources.layout.layoutPath = "/path/to/layouts/"
resources.view.scriptPath = "/path/to/scripts/"
```